# PHP: preserve order of array_values

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an associative array that is structured like

```
(
    1 => 'a',
    2 => 'b',
    0 => 'c'
)
```

where all of the keys are numeric, will `array_values` ALWAYS guarantee that the values occur chronologically, in the new array, based on their previous keys' values, i.e. `['c', 'a', 'b']`?

If not, how can I accomplish this instead?

Comment: numeric keys points to indexed array, not associative

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Not always. In this case the keys are sequential, but what if they weren't, such as 1, 3, and 5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `array_values()` will not reorder the values in any way. It doesn't care about keys.

Its effective implementation is basically this:

```
function array_values_impl(array $array)
{
    $newArray = [];

    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $newArray[] = $item;
    }

    return $newArray;
}
```

If you want to sort the array using the keys, use [`ksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish by first sorting the array with keys and getting values by array_values function.

For example

```
 $array = array(
    1 => 'a',
   2 => 'b',
   0 => 'c'
);

ksort($array);
print_r(array_values($array));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => c
    [1] => a
    [2] => b
)
```